# How to enable proxy with username and password using undetected_chromium?

Tags: python, google-chrome, proxy, helper, undetected-chromedriver

I am using undetected_chromedriver but i can't get the proxy to work i don't know what's the issue as my code runs smooth but still don't enables the proxy.
I have working proxy with username and password  but i can't make it work
My chrome session starts but it shows the current Ip does not changes it

My Code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import os
import zipfile
import time

host = '91.201.40.130'
port = 12115
username = 'alos081100RnC5'
password = 'YRhSahmNYX'


manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
          singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
          },
          bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
      };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (host, port , username, password)


def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    return driver 

def main():
    driver = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True)
    driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com")
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your proxy. And then iterate it.

Comment: the same code works with selenium but not with undetected_chromedriver .IDK how to map that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try seleniumwire with uc: [https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#certificates:~:text=driver.wait_for_request()%20etc.-,Proxies,-If%20the%20site](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#certificates:%7E:text=driver.wait_for_request()%20etc.-,Proxies,-If%20the%20site)

Worked for me